# Who is in charge of creating fake logos and products for movies/games, and what are good examples of them?

Tags: games, packaging

Who is responsible for creating such products? Are they usually done by the props team? Or are there companies that specialise in them?

Here are a couple of examples. It's usually easier to find logos, so I'm more interested in good examples for graphic design such as product packaging, printed material and such.

Logos:

[image]

Packaging, Sin City Booze bottle:

http://www.chericocreative.com/images/photoAlbum/readImage.aspx?x=CvDI5DuXJOPXb733IVuGRbSftzA8rNbRaw5IwegkMF5BJbaHWVBlQ8bCrahex6IW7Qco9Kw2a9%2fnkCaL%2fHID4%2bOJJ7mKrQp%2fxxzqS06fnifLJU35VSBX5922xnzKtbTrsxVJaYmmzsTkyY92RHkijre5dG7O391P

Packaging, Dharma Initiative:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Apparently the wiki-style discussions of the past are now verboten on the SE network. Something I'm bummed about. It's a good topic. I do like what Pixar has done with a lot of their set props.

Comment: The Self-Evaluation http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/334/graphic-design-self-evaluation-lets-get-critical?cb=1 was what motivated me to do a wiki question. If it gets closed, at least I hope the meta thread was read.

Comment: This *is* a good topic. Can't we figure out how to make it a question so we can keep talking about it?

Comment: I like the "concept" of the question.. but there's no solvable issue. It's a fabulous discussion topic, but I still feel it's off topic for the GD problem <> answer format.

Comment: Edited to make it a question. The answer would be quite straightforward, but it leaves space to show some interesting examples :)

Comment: @DA01, not everyone speaks German here...

Comment: I don't understand the question here, what is 'fake' about these logos?

Comment: @poepje verboten is such a great word, though.

Comment: IF you know what it means, that is.

Comment: @poepje Verboten means "forbidden" (http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/verboten). I called the logos fake because they don't exist in the 'real world': For example, Aperture is from the game Portal and BnL is from the movie Wall-E.

Comment: I know (after all I knew it's German) but most people don't.

Comment: Ok I understand the 'fake' part now, thx. Perhaps you could mention this in the question so that it's instantly clear to everyone? This might get you more/better answers :D

Comment: Pixar's stuff has a lot of in-jokes as well (e.g., the lamp and ball from "Luxo, Jr." appear in every film). I believe B&L is named after Brad Lewis, who produced the previous two Pixar films.

Comment: Verboten may be uncommon, but it's part of the English language, as are deja vu, zeitgeist, et cetera.

Comment: Some of those are very effective. When I saw the Aperture Labs logo I thought "Oops, that's not made up!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logos and other graphics are generally designed by game artists. The game artists help design everything from sprites, textures, user interfaces, and yes the logos.

The fake products are usually idealized by designers, and level designers. They do not need other companies to do it for them, that's why they work in development teams. They can all use their skills to the best potential to make their game.

Comment: The sample logos aren't from games.

Comment: The first one is.

Answer (score 3):

Prop department or companies that specialise in them. I found some more interesting examples.

And for the downvoter: [It is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Red Apple Cigarettes from Quentin Tarantino:

[image]

Heisler Beer from My Name is Earl, Weeds and United States of Tara:

[image]

Gannon Car Rentals from Lost and Heroes:

[image]

Mooby's Franchise from Dogma and Clerks II:

[image]

And my favourite, Acme Products :)

[image]

EDIT:

I found these amazing magazines from Blade Runner and thought them as a good addition to the answer. I doubt many directors/producers would dedicate this much effort to productions now:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Acme actually was a real company that made anvils - I use one at the forge I go to. They were actually sold by a number of companies including Sears.